# how to pass bluetooth device name to another activity?

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am trying to pass Bluetooth device name and RSSI from one activity that contain the ListView to another activity,it works fine when the user choose one device but when the user choose another device the result will be the same for the first device. is there away to pass the name and RSSI or a Bluetooth device ??

```
newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
           Intent intent = new Intent(DevicesList.this, FindIT.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", NAME);
            intent.putExtra("rssi", RSSI);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

here is the code i use to send the intent

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BLUETOOTH_NAME", bluetoothName);
intent.putExtra("RSSI", rssi);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this case you save your data in the intent and pass it to the next activity every time you go from one activity to another. Then you can get your data in the new activity like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String bluetoothName = extras.getString("BLUETOOTH_NAME");
    String rssi = extras.getString("RSSI");
}
```

Comment: it's the same code i am using and getting wrong response...i think i should put the variable in the the onclick but i don't know how :(

Comment: Do you change the value of your variables after you finish the discovery of the bluetooth? Maybe you don't change the value of the variables bluetoothName and rssi when you  want to pass the again to the second activity through the intent.

Comment: how to do this ??  ...sorry am very new with android programming

Comment: i put them in the broadcast !! i think i should put them inside onclick put don't know how !!

Comment: for example you could try with `NAME = mBtAdapter.getName();` after your line `mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();`

Comment: maybe this tutorial could be useful for you http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/bluetooth/bluetoothadapter/android-bluetooth-example/ There is a whole code that shows how to get the names of the paired bluetooth devices and how to search for new devices

Comment: i have the code to search for paired and non paired devices ...thank you anyway :)